# Using ImageIdentify

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

How long does it take ImageIdentify to give an answer for one image? Also, I suppose using it requires an Internet connection with Wolfram servers. Is that correct?

Comment: It downloads data just like `CountryData` etc., after that it is quick. A test image of flowers of size 2000x1329 took 0.5 seconds. This question would have been answered quickly in the chat by the way.

Comment: The first time I ran it on the Lena test image, it downloaded data for quite a while (maybe close to a minute on a home cable connection). After that, it took 0.088s to identify the image. The result was "person". Also yes, it does need to establish a connection to the Wolfram Knowledge base, whatever that is exactly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you got V10.1 you can test it yourself. Make sure `ImageIdentify` got it's data after say 1st execution and then it can work offline. But use it online from time to time because it is a learning function and it becomes better with time, needs updated data. To understand better the workings, implications and applications of this function take a look also at [imageidentify.com](https://www.imageidentify.com/) project which is based of this function and is a spectacular example of interation of deep neural networks, [Wolfram Data Framework](http://www.wolfram.com/data-framework/?source=nav) (Wolfram|Alpha, [Entety](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Entity.html)) and [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/). I recommend reading the how [it works section](https://www.imageidentify.com/about/how-it-works).

```
i = Import["https://wolfr.am/4RvEuxmc"]
```

[image]

```
i // ImageDimensions
```

> {1920, 1080}

```
imgs = ImageResize[i, #] & /@ Range[200, 2000, 200];
```

Here we go OFFLINE:

```
Block[{$AllowInternet = False},
 dat = Flatten[{ByteCount[#], AbsoluteTiming[ImageIdentify[#]]}] & /@ imgs;]
```

So recognition is scale invariant:

```
dat // TableForm
```

[image]

And here are the times plotted:

```
ListLinePlot[dat[[All, ;; 2]], PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 FrameLabel -> {ByteCount, AbsoluteTiming}]
```

[image]

But I think this timings also will improve with time. For the benchmark this was on Mac 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7.

Comment: What happens if the result is wrong? How does Wolfram improve their classifier. For instance, I gave it a picture of a European badger and it thought it was an opossum, then an armadillo.

Comment: @Histograms "ImageIdentify is being progressively enhanced, especially with training data derived from feedback given by users of this site." - that from the page I linked above and said: "I recommend reading the how it works section."

Comment: Just FYI: There should be a factor 3 speedup for the upcoming 10.2.

Comment: I understand why it has to connect to the internet, but why does it need to connect to an account?!